# Connect Google domain to GoDaddy host

Tags: domain, hosting, web-hosting, godaddy

I recently purchased a domain through Google Domains, this is not a Google Apps for business account. It is strictly a domain purchase through google domains from my account. I then bought a simple linux economy hosting with cPanel from GoDaddy. I cannot seem to find a way to connect my google domain to my godaddy host, I have looked around and all the intructions I see always reference a Google Apps for Business account, which I have not created. If anyone could point me in the right direction of connecting the domain to the host without having to pay the GoDaddy transfer fee that would be very appreciated.